# Requiring packages inside a function R

Tags: r, function, dplyr, package

I have a question, I am making a package in R (just for me).

So I am scripting my function `sets` and inside `sets`  I use a lot of `dplyr` functions.

How can I make that if you're gonna use my package you must have `dplyr`.

I think is with `require()` inside the function? I was reading about this function and got more confused.

I was thinking it should go like this:

```
sets <- function(base, start, end, f_hor, freq=12){
  require(dplyr, lubridate)
  train <- base %>% 
    filter(year(date)>=as.Date(start)) %>% 
    filter(year(date)<=as.Date(end)) %>% select(-date)
  
  train <- ts(train, 
              start=c(year(as.Date(start)),month(as.Date(start))),
              end=c(year(as.Date(end)),month(as.Date(end))),
              frequency = freq)

  test <- base %>% 
    filter(year(date)<as.Date(end)) %>% select(-date)
  
  test <- head(test, f_hor)
  
  list <- list(train, test)
  names(list) <- c("train", "test")
  return(list)
}
```

Am I right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would likely want to include it in your `roxygen` skeleton at the top of your function using the `@import` tag. You could also consider using `@importFrom`

Something like:

```
#' My function called sets
#'
#' @param base ...
#' @param start
#' @param end
#' @param f_hor
#' @param freq
#'
#' @return a list...
#' 
#' @import dplyr
#' @import lubridate
#' @importFrom lubridate year month
#' 
#' @export
sets <- function(base, start, end, f_hor, freq = 12){
  
}
```

Additionally, within your function, you can opt to explicitly call a function from a specific package, i.e:

```
sets <- function(base, start, end, f_hor, freq = 12){
  train <- base %>% 
    dplyr::filter(lubridate::year(date)>=as.Date(start)) %>% 
    dplyr::filter(lubridate::year(date)<=as.Date(end)) %>% select(-date)
}
```

Comment: How can I not call the package explicitly? Is there any way to make a preference? Maybe with `conflict_prefer()`?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Roxygen, do it as @Matt said.  If you're not, then you need to do this:  list the packages you want in the `Imports:` list in your `DESCRIPTION` file, e.g.

```
Imports:  lubridate, dplyr
```

This guarantees that your package won't load without having those two packages available.

You also need to do one of the following:

List the imported functions in your `NAMESPACE` file, e.g.

```
importFrom(lubridate, year, month)
```

and then just use them as if they are locally defined, or use the `::` prefix every time you call them, e.g.

```
lubridate::year(date)
```

I'm not sure how these two steps correspond to the Roxygen tags.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. It is obligatory that I have to call all the functions by `::` or is there another way?

Comment: The first method I suggested doesn't need `::`.

Comment: Yes, I noticed, sorry I misread my error. I've got a question. How do I prefer some packages? In a simple script, I'd use `conflict_prefer()`

Comment: If you have a different question, you should post it.  I don't know how this would ever come up, so you'll need to post details of how to reproduce the issue.